# Trouble passing clicked value (PHP) to ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble passing the value of the clicked element into an ajax function. Below is the ajax function.

```
// Get values from all three dropdown menus
        var state = $('#states').val();
        var status = $('#status').val();
        var services = $('#services').val();
// Get value from clicked element
        var pagedtest = pagednum;

function do_ajax() {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl, 
                data: {
                    'action' : 'json_info2',
                    'state' : state,
                    'status' : status,
                    'services' : services,
                    'pagedtest' : pagedtest
                },
                success:function(moredata) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    $('#project-list').html( moredata );
                    $('#project-list').fadeIn();
                }/*,
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    var errorMsg = "No results match your criteria";
                    $('#project-list').html(errorMsg);
                }*/
            }); // end of ajax call
        } // end of function do_ajax
```

Then let's say I have a series of  tags that are each assigned a title dynamically, like this:

```
<a title="90" class="page-link">90</a>
<a title="87" class="page-link">87</a>
<a title="102" class="page-link">102</a>
```

And I'm trying to run the following code in my php page in order to pick up the clicked value to pass to ajax.

```
$(".page-link").click(function() {
      var pagednum = $(".page-link").val($(this).attr('title'));
      return false;
});
```

When I click one of the links, nothing happens. Where am I going wrong?

How can I pass the value of the title attribute, of the clicked tag, when the ajax function runs?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: What are you trying to assign to `pagednum`?

Comment: Are the `.page-link` elements appended to the DOM via the AJAX request? Also note that `a` elements do not have a `value` attribute so using the `val()` method here is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(".page-link").click(function() {
       var pagednum = $(this).attr('title');
 });
```

Also, ensure your anchor tags have href attributes.

Comment: It seems pretty clear the the php script is returning html: `$('#project-list').html( moredata );`. So setting the data type to json will break it. Also note that this function does not do anything: It sets a local variable that gets destroyed as soon as the function ends.

Comment: Oops, didnt see that. My bad.

Comment: Yes, the json data type would break it. OllyTenerife's answer is correct, I was just going about it the wrong way. I'm going to post another answer below to explain what I was doing incorrectly, as my initial question may have been a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what the relation between those two sections of javascript is, but it seems you are trying to use `pagednum` in the first section.

However, the `pagednum` you have defined in your click hander looks like this:

```
$(".page-link").click(function() {
      var pagednum = $(".page-link").val($(this).attr('title'));
//    ^^^ defining a variable in the local scope
      return false;
});
```

As you declare the variable with the `var` keyword **inside** the click handler, the scope of that variable is local to that function, the click handler.

If you need a global variable, so should declare it globally (outside of any jQuery function) like:

```
var pagednum;
// rest of scripts, functions, etc.
```

And then you use it in your click handler like:

```
$(".page-link").click(function() {
      pagednum = $(".page-link").val($(this).attr('title'));
//    ^^^^^^^^ use global variable
      return false;
});
```

For more details it would be helpful to post the complete script so we can see how everything relates.

Answer (score 0):

This post will, hopefully, clarify what I was asking above, as well as how it was solved.

I have a php page, and on that page I have several elements that have a title attribute. I originally was using a tags for this, but I decided to switch to li's. So I have these on my php page:

```
<li title="87" class="page-link">Click this 87</li>
<li title="2" class="page-link">Click this 2</li>
<li title="34" class="page-link">Click this 34</li>
```

What I wanted to do was click on of those li's, get the title value, save it as a variable, and pass it to an ajax function. I initially tried including a jquery click function (in my PHP page) to get the value. I was able to successfully get the value on click, but I was still having trouble passing it to the ajax function.

So instead, I went to my ajax function (which is located in an external js file called ajaxLoop.js). Inside that js file, I added the following:

```
// make pagination clickable after filter
        $( ".page-link" ).click(function() {
            var pagednumtest = $(this).attr('title');
            alert("the set number is "+pagednumtest);
            run_ajax();
        }); // end of click function for states
```

This was successfully grabbing the value on click, as the alert was able to output it, but I still couldn't access var pagednumtest in the actual ajax function. In fact, the ajax function wouldn't run because it didn't recognize the variable that I was trying to pass. So I modified the above function by passing the variable to the ajax function like this:

I changed

```
run_ajax();
```

to this

```
run_ajax(pagednumtest);
```

So the entire function then looked like this:

```
// make pagination clickable after filter
        $( ".page-link" ).click(function() {
            var pagednumtest = $(this).attr('title');
            alert("the set number is "+pagednumtest);
            // variable is passed to the ajax function
            run_ajax(pagednumtest);
        }); // end of click function for states
```

The ajax function then accepted the variable value, and I was able to use it.

```
function run_ajax(mynumber) {
// Get values from all three dropdown menus
        var state = $('#states').val();
        var markets = $('#markets').val();
        var services = $('#services').val();
        var mytestnumber = mynumber;
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl, 
                data: {
                    'action' : 'json_info2',
                    // ignore state, markets, and services as they are dropdown menu values
                    'state' : state,
                    'status' : markets,
                    'services' : services,
                    // here I was able to get and use the clicked value
                    'testnum' : mytestnumber
                },
                success:function(moredata) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    $('#project-list').html( moredata );
                    $('#project-list').fadeIn();
                }/*,
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    var errorMsg = "No results match your criteria";
                    $('#project-list').html(errorMsg);
                }*/
            }); // end of ajax call
        } // end of function do_ajax
```